# Prove that the set $X = \{x \in R^L_+| u(x) \geq \bar u\}$ is closed

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Prove that the set $X = \{x \in R^L_+| u(x) \geq \bar u\}$ is closed.

Saw this statement in the textbook but I'm not sure how this is the case when we don't have any restrictions on $u(x)$ such as continuity. I can prove this if it is continuous, but I'm not sure how to do it if  isn't.

Comment: Related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/12411/42

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't quite answer my question. I don't think this is true unless u () is continuous. The book says that this is closed due to $u(x) \geq \bar{u}$ and $x \in R^L_+$ but that doesn't seem quite true to me. This statement implies that the upper contour set is always closed no matter what the preference is, but this can't be true.

Comment: Are you sure you're not leaving out any context? Which textbook are you using?

Comment: MGW but the solutions manual, which is not written by the authors of the book.

Comment: At the beginning of Section 3.D, MWG do make a few assumptions that affect the rest of the chapter, and $u(x)$ being continuous is one of them.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but then in the exercises sometimes it is specified clearly that u(x) is continuous and sometimes it is not, so I get kinda confused on that.

Comment: And also in the solutions, the exact phrasing was "X is closed because of $u(x) \geq \bar{u}$ and $x \in R^L_+$" which doesn't seem to necessitate the continuity condition to me.

Answer (score 1):

The statement does not seem to be true.

Define $u$ as $u(x) = -1$ if $x \leq 0$, $u(x) = 0$ if $x \in (0,1)$ and $u(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 1$. The set of points $x$ for which $u(x) \geq 0$ is $(0,\infty)$, which is not closed.

Comment: Why did you need the $u(x)=1$ part?

Comment: @domotorp If $u$ is a utility function then universal domain and monotonicity are usual assumptions.

Comment: I mean why can't that be also 0?

Comment: @domotorp It could be.